# TensorRT weight order compare to Tensorflow [H,W,IN_C,OUT_C]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I have to manually add a convolution layer as I have some special operation which is not supported by the Tensorflow parser. What is the order of the weights does the TensorRT expect to read from a .wts file? For example, a conv2d weight tensor of Tensorflow typically has an order of[H,W,IN_CHANNEL,OUT_CHANNEL]. I know that TensorRT expects the input data to be in the NCHW order, but is the order of weights has to be changed too when it's being writed to .wts file? If so, what is the order TensorRT expected to get? [IN_CHANNEL, OUT_CHANNEL,H,W]?

Answer (score 0):

Quick summary ... if you are asking about weights sort order, you may also be concerned with input data order as well. The answer posted here probably gets you most of what you need on both counts: [Run Tensorflow with NVIDIA TensorRT Inference Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142284/run-tensorflow-with-nvidia-tensorrt-inference-engine)

Additional details … I recently worked through these issues using custom tools, and here are the relevant factors I encountered:

- input image data order, which is NHWC for tensorflow and NCHW for tensorrt; and within the channel in the image, the color order, e.g. RGB vs BGR
- weights sort orders by layer

  - for a 2D convolution, tensorflow uses RSCK ([filter_height, filter_width, input_depth, output_depth]) and tensorrt uses KCRS.
  - for a dense layer following a 2D convolution or pooling layer, adjust the weights sort order for a different flattening sequence, effectively converting RSCK for tensorflow to KCRS for tensorrt, where now R and S refer to the entire input layer height and width, respectively, the C is the input_depth as before, and now the output depth K is the neuron count of the dense layer
  - for a dense layer following dense layer, convert CK to KC order

(note: this answer assumes you are not using groups in any of the convolutions)